# How to detect how much handles the application is using

Tags: java, swt

For our SWT-based application we are getting relatively often the SWT error "no more handles". To detect whether the problem is in our code, how to detect - **using code in our application** - how much handles our application actually is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baz' tip for Sleak gave me the idea:

```
final DeviceData data = new DeviceData();
data.tracking = true;
display = new Display(data);
```

and then in regular intervals I log the number from

```
final int handleCount = display.getDeviceData().objects.length
```

Unfortunately, detecting the number of widgets (I guess, they are using handles, too) is not possible so easily.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably getting the following exception:

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

You may be creating resources (such as Font, Image or GC objects) that you aren't correctly disposing.You might want to take a moment to read through [SWT guide on Managing Operating System Resources.](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html)

To determine if this is indeed the case, I can recommend this useful article: [Diagnosing Handle Leaks in SWT/RCP Windows Applications](http://i-proving.com/2006/06/05/diagnosing-handle-leaks-in-swtrcp-windows-applications/).

Use Sleak, it is also a way to  monitor your resources.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Processes" tab of the Windows Task Manager you can add the "Handles" column, showing the handles all your process use in real time.

Comment: Of course, this is only a solution if you're using Windows. Still +1